# How to update the angular2 version to the latest

Tags: angular

I am trying to update my angular2 project version to rc.6 for using @NgModule({}) but i am not sure about it,can any one please suggest me help.

Comment: Check this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Answer (score 1):

I used this command to update my angular 2 app and it worked.

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm update --save` will update all packages inside package.json to their latest version according to their defined version range.

If you want to update from a version prior to 2.0.0-rc.1, then you'll need to manually edit package.json, as Angular was split into several npm modules. Without this, as angular2 package points to 2.0.0-beta.17, you'll never get to use the latest version of Angular. 
A list with some of the most common modules that you'll need to get started can be found in the [quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#config-files).